# Messed up srand() and vector::iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, srand

I have written a practice code for a 'battle' that allows you to select number of combatants, number of rounds and number of dice-rolls per fighter per round storing the result into a 3D vector array. The storage part is working; however, the printResult() function is botched (i have put a // before it in main() ) and the srand() isnt working either. The complete program is below for convenience:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Combat{
    private:
        int numberOfRounds;
        int numberOfCombatants;
        int numberOfRolls;
        int sidesDie;
        vector <int> rollz;
        vector <vector <int> >combatant;
        vector <vector <vector <int> > > round;
    public:
        void printMenu();
        void battle();
        void printResult();
        Combat(int, int , int, int );
        Combat(int );
        Combat();
        int roll();
        int roll(int die);
};
void Combat::printMenu()
{
    cout<<setw (10)<<"Welcome to the Combat Menu";
    cout<<'\n'<<setw (10)<<"Choose:";
    cout<<'\n'<<setw (10)<<"Number of combatants: ";
    cin>>numberOfCombatants;
    cout<<'\n'<<setw (10)<<"Die sides:";
    cin>>sidesDie;
    cout<<'\n'<<setw (10)<<"Enter number of rounds: ";
    cin>>numberOfRounds;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"Enter number of rolls (per combatant per round):";
    cin>>numberOfRolls;
}
Combat::Combat(){
    numberOfRounds=8;
}
Combat::Combat(int x){
    x=numberOfRounds;
}
Combat::Combat(int rnds,int cmb,int rll, int sides){
    numberOfRounds=rnds;
    numberOfCombatants=cmb;
    numberOfRolls=rll;
    sidesDie=sides;
}
int Combat::roll(int die)
{
    die=sidesDie;
    srand(time(0));
    int r=(1+rand()%die);
    return r;

}
int Combat::roll(){
    srand(time(0));
    int r=(1+rand()%6);
    return r;
  }
void Combat::battle(){
    cout<<setw(10)<<" Computing results of battle ...\n";
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<numberOfRounds;++i){
        cout<<"\nRound number "<<i+1;
        round.push_back(combatant);
        for(j=0;j<numberOfCombatants;++j){
            cout<<"\nCombatant number "<<j+1;
            combatant.push_back(rollz);
            cout<<endl;

            for(k=0;k<numberOfRolls;++k){
                rollz.push_back(roll(sidesDie));
                cout<<rollz.at(k)<<'\t';
            }
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

void Combat::printResult(){
    cout<<endl;
    vector< vector <vector<int> > >::const_iterator it1;
    int combt, counter=0;
    for (it1=round.begin();it1 !=round.end();++it1){
        ++counter;

        cout<<"\nRound number "<<counter<<endl;
        for(vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator it2=combatant.begin();it2!=combatant.end();++it2){
            ++combt;
            cout<<"\nCombatant "<<combt<<" hits ";
                  for(vector<int>::const_iterator it3=rollz.begin();it3!=rollz.end();++it3){
                cout<<*it3<<'\t';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    Combat fight;
    fight.printMenu();
    fight.battle();
    //fight.printResult();
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Comment: "Isn't working" is a hard place to start. Can you define how it's not working? Exceptions? Compiler errors? Because your srand looks fine to me...

Comment: through a single run of the program all dice-rolls are the same number throughout the entire matrix

Comment: Just noticed that you're reseeding it every time just before you use rand(), you only need to seed the RNG once in the lifetime of your program. Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: That sorted part of the issue, though now all rollz for a combatant are repeated for each one of them in all rounds. Uurgh! Plus, can you help me with the printResult() function ? thats messed up too. thanks

Comment: To explain Corey's comment: you should call `srand()` once - probably at the top of `main()` - NOT before every call to `rand()`.  (The random number generator isn't truely random - it follows a sequence.  If you seed it with the same number, it will restart that sequence....)

Comment: I did that and now i get new scores but now they are repeated for each player and each round. So for 2 player, rolling 3 times in 5 rounds i have a single set of rolls repeated 5 x 2 = 10 times : i think my my push_back function for each combatant vector is sharing the same rolls instead of generating new ones

Comment: possible duplicate of [rand function returns same values when called within a single function c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729214/rand-function-returns-same-values-when-called-within-a-single-function-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems you should tackle separately (and which you should have solved separately before you put them together into one code base). Loki Asteri has already addressed the problem with `srand()`.

It looks as if `round` is a vector of `Combatant`, which is a vector of something else, but look here:

```
void Combat::printResult(){
    ...
    for (it1=round.begin();it1 !=round.end();++it1){
        ++counter;
        cout<<"\nRound number "<<counter<<endl;
        // You never use counter or it1 again.
        // You iterate over the same combatant for each it1:
        for(vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator it2=combatant.begin();
            it2!=combatant.end();++it2){
            ++combt;
            cout<<"\nCombatant "<<combt<<" hits "; // bad variable name at best
            // And now you iterate over the same rollz 
            // for every entry in combatant.
            for(vector<int>::const_iterator it3=rollz.begin();
                it3!=rollz.end();++it3){
                cout<<*it3<<'\t';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah its screwed up, I do not know how to code :) trying to use this-> to get the correct results. Not sure. thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Only call srand() once in an application.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    // STUFF
}
```

Comment: Done that, only randomizes one instance of rollz which are repeated afterwards. (you can check this prgrm yourself) the second issue is that printResult() function which just outputs a large number '1's so i have commented it out until i fix the die-randomization bug