# c++ random numbers srand

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rand function returns same values when called within a single function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729214/rand-function-returns-same-values-when-called-within-a-single-function-c)

I have a program which creates a new set of random numbers each mouse click. If I run the program without srand ( time(NULL) ); the numbers are the same each time. If I run the program WITH srand ( time(NULL) ); then it's possible for me to spam click and the numbers will repeat themselves. How can I get around this?

Comment: Use `srand` once.

Comment: Call `srand()` once (and only once) in your program. Probably at start up.

Comment: What do you mean by "spam click"?

Comment: I mean I can click really fast on the screen and the numbers are likely to repeat themselves - I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Of course, with many pseudo-random number generators if you click many, many, many times, the numbers will repeat. But that's not your problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is about seeding the random number generator with the same value. The `srand` function is for initializing the so called "seed" for it. A seed can be used to generate the same random numbers in a sequence.

First you need to initialize the generator then just call the `rand` function without arguments, and it will generate random numbers. For example:

```
  /* initialize random seed with actual date-time */
  std::srand(std::time(NULL));

  /* generate ten random number lower than 10 */
  int random, times = 10;
  while(times){
    random = std::rand() % 10;
    times--;
  }
```

About the "spam click": `std::time(NULL)` has precision in seconds, so you're initializing the random seed with the same value if you click within the same second.

Here is an example [on the official c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) site,
and another example on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) too.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not only not official, it contains many errors and is thus not well regarded here. Try [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), they try to adhere to the actual standard.

Comment: Modified it accordingly, thx.

Answer (score 0):

`rand` function is not very good at generating random numbers, take a look at `boost::random`. it is awesome and can create random and semi random numbers