# Generating two ( or multiple) uniformly distributed random numbers c++

Tags: c++, random

I would like to generate several uniformly distributed random numbers in the same pass.
So far I have a "standard" function for generating a random number

```
double generateRandomNumber()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    double r=((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
    return r;
}
```

how ever when in main I call it like that:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <cmath>
# include <ctime>

int main()
{

    // generate random number
    double rr1=generateRandomNumber();
    double rr2=generateRandomNumber();
    cout << rr1 << endl;
    cout << rr2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get that both numbers are the same ( I guess its the time limitations of seconds), anyways, this is something I would like to generelize to multiple random numbers.

Can anyone suggest a better way? maybe using a different method or library?

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva, Cheers, I'll check it out

Comment: There are hundreds of Q&A on here (e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729214/rand-function-returns-same-values-when-called-within-a-single-function-c)) explaining how `srand()` should be called once (typically just inside `main()`), as it resets the random number sequence and calls with the same seed will restart at the same point therein.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `srand` every time beore using `rand`.
`srand` should be call only once on the program begins.

You can use static variable to see if `srand` is previously called.

```
double generateRandomNumber()
{
    static bool initialized = false;
    if (!initialized)
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        initialized = true;
    }
    double r=((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: @ MikeCAT why do you declare the static variables every time you enter the function, should'nt it be declared once?

Comment: Hmmm, I can say that this is bad idea if there are multiple random numbber generating functions such as `int generateRandomInteger()`. Calling `srand` at the beginning of `main` function or wrapping `rand()` with a program which calls `srand` if needed is better.

Comment: anyways , this does not solve the problem, this part runs fast, and the random numbers I get are still the same.

Comment: This code [seems working well in Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/E5gALbxGJwExCTpM9).

Comment: @jarhead Stop calling srand more than once! It is also clear that you don't understand how static local variables work. You really should put that right.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine now, Cheers

Comment: @MikeCAT, I just don't get yet the procedure that is done here....could you elaborate on that more?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, If you want to help then help, atm your comments are not useful at all

Comment: @jarhead If you want to learn, then you'll heed my advice and learn about static locals.

Comment: `static` variables in functions are initialized only once at the beginning of program. First call of this function: `initialized = false`, `srand` is called and `initlaized` becomes `true`. Second call or later: `initlaized` is still `true`, so no `srand` is called here.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to have the function seed the generator. That creates an undesirable coupling. For instance a caller cannot seed to reproduce a specific sequence. It's also wasteful to test `initialized` every time. I would very strongly recommend putting the requirement to seed on the caller.

Comment: @MikeCAT, I removed the static variable to be global ( outside of the function and main), I still get good results

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, how would you do that then? would you mind posting an example?

Comment: @jarhead Remove everything related to `initialized` and instead call `srand` exactly once in `main`. Did you read the link that I gave in comments to the question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it also works well after removing initialized, Cheers

Comment: Make sure you remember to seed though, in `main`, before the first call to `rand`.