# rand() returns the same value, even after a srand

Tags: c++, random, ogre

I am trying to get a random value, but that doesn't work.

I use this for exemple.

```
  srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid());

  int a = rand() % 100;
```

I get a random value the first time, but every other time I call rand(), I get the same value.

My full code :

```
Worms::Worms(std::string const& name, Ogre::SceneManager *scene,
  Ogre::ColourValue &color, unsigned char hp) :
  _name(name), _hp(hp), _scene(scene), _color(color)
{
  srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid());
  std::cout << "creating worms" << name << std::endl;
  std::cout << color << std::endl;
  this->_ent = scene->createEntity(name, "Worm.mesh");
  this->generatePosition();
  this->setColor(color);
}

void                            Worms::generatePosition()
{
  int a = rand() % 10;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  Ogre::Vector3 pos(rand() % 800 + 100 , 450, 0);
  std::cout << pos << std::endl;
  this->_node = this->_scene->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(this->_name);
  this->_node->attachObject(this->_ent);
  this->_node->showBoundingBox(true);
  this->_node->scale(_node->getScale() * 4);
  _node->rotate(Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_X, Ogre::Degree(90));
  _node->rotate(Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z, Ogre::Degree(90));
  _node->setPosition(pos);
}
```

And the output :

```
4
Vector3(498, 450, 0)
creating worms K04L4_1
creating wormsK04L4_1 Captain_2
ColourValue(1, 0, 0, 0)
4
Vector3(498, 450, 0)
creating worms K04L4_1
creating wormsK04L4_1 Captain_3
ColourValue(1, 0, 0, 0)
4
Vector3(498, 450, 0)
creating worms K04L4_1
ok
creating wormsOP3X_2 Pride_1
ColourValue(0, 1, 0, 0)
4
Vector3(498, 450, 0)
creating worms OP3X_2
creating wormsOP3X_2 Captain_2
ColourValue(0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Are you calling `srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid());` more than once?  If you call `srand()` with the same value from `time()`, that will reset the "random" number generation.

Comment: `rand()` is ---deprecated--- old and ugly. Consider using `<random>` instead.

Comment: Fyi, Unless there is only ONE `Worms` object *ever* created in your process (and judging by your output, that is NOT the case), that `srand` does not belong in that constructor; it belongs in a only-executed-once-ever block of code, usually the head of `main()`. And I concur with Bartek completely. [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) is what's for dinner for modern C++ programs, and I *strongly* encourage it.

Comment: [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729214/rand-function-returns-same-values-when-called-within-a-single-function-c) and consider how it applies in your situation.

Comment: Please also read about [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's easy to demonstrate this problem with only a few lines of *complete* code that anyone could compile.  And the point in question has nothing to do with ogre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using srand() more than one time in my program, now I call it once in my main() function and that works fine.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please remove it, and put into comment of your question

Comment: @Ajay Why? I'd say this is a valid answer. Not very detailed, maybe, but still an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`time(NULL)` only has second resolution so if your function is called within the same second it will always use the same seed. Try `GetTickCount()` for millisecond resolution or pass microsecond `ticks` into `srand()`

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto ticks = time_point_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();
```

The downcast from 64 to 32 bits (`srand()` takes 32 bit argument) is specific to the compiler but it usually discards the high order bits which is what you to want to get a more random seed.

As you said, you can call `srand()` once and then keep calling `rand()`. You'll then step through the entire pseudorandom sequence.

Comment: I am puzzled why you recommend `std::chrono` to replace `std::time` and don’t make the logical step of recommending `std::random` instead of `std::srand`.

Comment: Excellent point. The bugbears of pseudorandom number generators are short cycles and unsatisfactory randomness. I haven't used `std::random` so can't comment on it. I worked with statisticians a long time ago and they rolled their own PNG's so they could guarantee a decent cycle length before the sequence repeated and to pass a range of statistical randomness tests.